# Como saber se uma pessoa já visitou uma pagina nos últimos 2 dias

Tags: php, html, cookies

Estou com uma ideia, de mostrar anuncio só pra quem já visitou o site antes, e outro anuncio para quem nunca visitou antes.. (ÚLTIMOS 2 DIAS)

ALGO TIPOO ASSIM:

```html
<?php if ($visitou = sim): ?>
  APARECE ANUNCIO PRA QUEM JA VISITOU NAS ULTIMOS 2 DIAS
<?php else: ?>
  APARECE PRA QUEM NÃO VISITOU NOS ULTMIOS DOIS DIAS, (VAI SER ANUNCIO DIFERENTE)
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Utilizando [Cookies](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.cookies.php) ?

Comment: Pode me ajudar como fazer ?

Comment: Bom, agora estou impossibilitado de dar uma resposta pois não tenho como testar o código, talvez algum colega possa ajuda-lo.

Comment: Obrigado. Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você cria um `cookie` usando o `setcookie("nome_do_cookie", "valor_do_cookie", validade_do_cookie)`

Pra verificar:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['visitante'])) {
    if(!($_COOKIE['visitante'] === null)) {
        //O usuário já acessou seu site e as 48h não acabaram
        echo "O cookie é valido!";  
    } else {
        //O usuario já visitou seu site e as 48h acabarram
        echo "O cookie é invalido.";
    }
} else {
    // o cookie não existe
    // significa que o usuário nunca acessou ou apagou o cookie.
    setcookie("visitante","sim", time() + 172800);
}
```

No `isset` você garante que não vai acessar um indice nulo. No `if`, você verifica se o cookie existe, se ele existe então quer dizer que a pessoa já visitou seu site antes.

no time() você pega o tempo atual, e nos 172800 é o tempo em milissegundos equivalente a 48 horas.

É claro que um cookie é fácil de manipular. Você pode tentar pegar o máximo de informações possiveis do usuário (como ip, navegador, etc...) e salvar em algum lugar, pra verificar depois, isso se a regra de negócio necessitar disso.

Answer (score 0):

Se o cookie não existir mostra o anuncio de quem não visitou e cria o cookie valido por 2 dias. Enquanto o cookie for válido apresenta o anuncio correspondente.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_COOKIE['visitou'])){
    $visitou="block";
    $naoVisitou="none";

}else{

    $cookie_name = "visitou";
    $cookie_value = "sim";
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 2), "/"); // 86400 = 1 dia
    $visitou="none";
    $naoVisitou="block";

}

?>


<div style="display:<?php echo $visitou ?>">Visitou- cookie válido</div>

<div style="display:<?php echo $naoVisitou ?>">Não Visitou cookie expirado</div>
```